# Random value in output even after initializing the variables

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a , b;
 a = 2; 
 b = 3; 
 printf("%d , %d", a , b);
 return 0;
}
```

The output comes out to be ->

```
PS E:\Coding\C\C C++> cd "e:\Coding\C\C C++" ; if ($?) { gcc hello.c -o hello } ; if ($?) { .\hello }
4214884
```

Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with the compiler?

Comment: I suspect your command invocation is executing an old version of code.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.  When I compile and run it it prints `2 , 3`.  Your problem must be in something we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems okay, it should give the correct output.

After saving the code, compile the program again.

```
gcc file_name_with_extension
```

It'll create an execitable file. Then run that file by simply giving the name of the executable file without any extension.